# blobFromImage Assertion error using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, blob

I'm trying to run (not training) a Caffe network using OpenCV in Python.

My image (`img`) is a single channel `ndarray` of (48,118).

```py
# single channel to RGB like
frame = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3))
frame[:,:,0] = img
frame[:,:,1] = img
frame[:,:,2] = img
```

Then I normalize it to 0-1.

```py
frame /= np.max(frame)
```

Finally I used the `blobFromImage` function to create a "blob" and later feed the net.

```py
inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, size=(368,368), mean=(0,0,0), swapRB=False, crop=False)
```

The problem happens after use the line above. It raises an assertion error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\helde\code\main.py in 
----> 67 inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, size=(368,368), mean=(0,0,0), swapRB=False, crop=False)

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:177: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) image.depth() == 5 in function 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v5::blobFromImages'
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't like to answer my own question but, I'll in case someone else have the same problem.

The solution is pretty simple, the OpenCV's `blobFromImage` needs the image in a `uint8` format.

So, in my case, the variable `frame` is grayscale and previously I scaled it to 0-1:

```py
frame /= np.max(frame)
```

in this case, the new frame is `float`.

The correct wait, to work with `blobFromImage`, turning it in `uint8` would be:

```py
img = ((frame / np.max(frame)) * 255).astype('uint8')
```

you need this `....astype('uint8')` otherwise you'll have something with pixel values between 0-255 BUT still in `float` format.

## Example: Grayscale image

Suppose we have a `float` image (`img`) that we want to pre-process with `blobFromImage` with dimensions 100x100:

```py
print(img.shape, type(img), img.dtype)
(48, 118) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> float64
```

Now, converting it to grayscale as mentioned before

```py
img = ((img / np.max(img)) * 255).astype('uint8')
```

Just to check:

```py
print(img.shape, type(img), img.dtype)
(48, 118) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> uint8
```

Now we can apply the `blobFromImage`:

```py
inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 
                                size=(368,368), 
                                mean=(0,0,0), 
                                swapRB=False, 
                                crop=False)
```

Now, you must to have something 4D:

```py
print(inpBlob.shape, type(inpBlob), inpBlob.dtype)
(1, 1, 368, 368) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> float32
```

check!

## Example: RGB image

The `float` to `uint8` part is pretty much the same, the only difference is when replicating the image to have the 3 channels RGB. I'm going to put the whole code, and point out the replicate part:

```py
# we start with the same float image (img) as before

# converting to uint8. Still one channel
img = ((img / np.max(img)) * 255).astype('uint8')

print(img.shape, type(img), img.dtype)
(48, 118) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> uint8

# replicating the only channel 3 times. There are other ways to do this:
img_rgb = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
img_rgb[:,:,0], img_rgb[:,:,1], img_rgb[:,:,2] = img, img, img

# now you'll see a thrid dimension in the shape
print(img_rgb.shape, type(img_rgb), img_rgb.dtype)
(48, 118, 3) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> uint8

# applying the blobFromImage function
inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img_rgb, 
                                size=(368,368), 
                                mean=(0,0,0), 
                                swapRB=False, 
                                crop=False)

# checking...
print(inpBlob.shape, type(inpBlob), inpBlob.dtype)
(1, 3, 368, 368) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> float32
# the 3 channels are reflected in the second component of inpBlop's shape.
```

As you saw, is pretty straightforward IF you change the thing to `uint8` before.